# Interpretation of output and prediction from cpglmm

Tags: r, predict, mixed-models

I am helping a colleague fit a Compound-Poisson Generalized Linear Mixed Model in R, using the `cpglmm`-function from the `cplm`-package ([link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cplm/cplm.pdf)). The model involves a three-way interaction and I would like to compute some interpretable quantities. So far, I have tried to calculate some Odds-ratios but I am not sure this is the right way to do it?

```
# Fit model with three-way interaction in fixed effects #

m <- cpglmm(ncs ~ diversity_index*diversity_speciality*n_authors + selfcit + 
n_refs + (1|region), data = diversity)

# Calculate Odds-ratio #
se <- sqrt(diag(vcov(m)))

tab <- cbind(Est = m$fixef, 
             S.E. = se, 
             LL = m$fixef - 1.96 * se, 
             UL = m$fixef + 1.96 * se)

print(exp(tab), digits=3)
```

I also want to compute some predicted values, e.g predicted probabilities or the like, but I can't get `predict()` to work for the `cpglmm`. Is there any functions I could use?